# Requesting focus to a EditText after another EditText has been touched?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, ontouchlistener

I have 2 `EditText` (`myEditText1` and `myEditText2`)
And I need when touch `myEditText1`
1. Do some business [No problem here and required business applied]
2. **Then request focus to `myEditText2`** [ No luck? ]

```
final EditText myEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText1);
final EditText myEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText2);

// ...

myEditText1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // My business when myEditText1 touched [ OK ]
        // ...

        // TODO
        // Need to request focus to another EditText myEditText2 ?

        return false;
    }
});
```

I try some solutions like following trials
But no luck and focusing still on `myEditText1`

```
myEditText2.requestFocus();
```

Related questions
[EditText request focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077755/edittext-request-focus)
[Change Focus to EditText Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794234/change-focus-to-edittext-android)

Comment: Also try removing focus from edit text1

Comment: you can also try this `myEditText1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an `OnClickListener` on your edit text like this:

```
this.editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your code
                editText2.requestFocus();
            }
});
```

Just take care about a *special case*
**onClick() is not called when the EditText doesn't have focus**
And you can find details of this case in the following question thread
[onClick event is not triggering | Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790573/onclick-event-is-not-triggering-android)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using TextWatcher, than use conditions to know when your business is done

try this:

```
myEditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(myEditText1.getText().length() > 3){
                myEditText2.requestFocus();
            }
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be because of the keyboard. You can try

```
myEditText2.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(myEditText2, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
public void requestFocus(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and use like,

```
requestFocus(myEditText2);
```